# Computing the Kalman filter measurement covariance matrix directly from measurement data?

Tags: kalman-filter

I'm looking into methods for estimating the parameters of a Kalman Filter, in particular the covariance matrices. I have seen it suggested a couple times (for example [here](https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/record.jsf?pid=diva2%3A1041201&dswid=-4462)) that the measurement covariance $\mathbf{R}$ can be approximated by computing the variance of measurement variables from a batch of sensor data. However try as I might I haven't been able to find a reference actually proving that this is (or isn't) OK. Can anyone point me to a research paper that provides either empirical evidence or a theoretical argument for or against this procedure? Or at least a likely original source for the idea?